# Training Loss or Validation Loss for Hyperparameter Optimisation

Tags: machine-learning, training, hyperparameter-tuning, hyperparameter, validation

When performing HO, should I be looking to train each model (each with different hyperparameter values, e.g. with RandomSearch picking those values) on the training data, and then the best one is picked? Or should I be looking to choose them judged on their performance on the validation set?

Answer (score -1):

There is a different method called nested cross validation that solves the problem you are dealing with here. Check out this post (https://machinelearningmastery.com/nested-cross-validation-for-machine-learning-with-python/) .... In my view this is the best HO method.